# App did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

My application on iTunes is rejected because:

"We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 8.1.3, which is a violation of the App Store Review Guidelines. Specifically, we did not find that the app showed the "Go" button when viewed on iPad."

Can anybody guide me, how I configure my app layout so that it will run properly on iPad?

[image: Running on iPad]
[image: Running on iPhone5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AutoLayout and fix the position of the button to the bottom right corner.